# Error when compiling sphinxbase in cygwin

Tags: cmusphinx

I tried to install sphinxbase on my Windows 7 using Cygwin for running pocketsphinx android demo.
But I got the following error after executing make:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base build/temp.cygwin-1.7.11-i686-2.6/sphinxbase.o -L../src/libsphinxbase/.libs -L/usr/lib/python2.6/config -lsphinxbase -liconv -lpython2.6 -o build/lib.cygwin-1.7.11-i686-2.6/sphinxbase.dll
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -liconv
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
Makefile:471: recipe for target `pymod-build-stamp' failed
make[1]: *** [pymod-build-stamp] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/psph/sphinxbase/python'
Makefile:330: recipe for target `all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1.
```

I visited the link http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~ecooper/CS4706/ps-cygwin.html and followed the steps, but to the same result.
I have used pocketsphinx-0.7 and sphinxbase-0.7 in above situation.

Comment: Is it the whole error? I think, there should be something else, before the log you pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error:

```
ld: cannot find -liconv
```

means, that you don't have iconv installed. Look for the package with the name `libiconv-dev` or similar in your package manager.

Comment: There is also short mention, in the attached instruction. Did you read the instruction and the error log, before asking here?

Comment: That means you have both libiconv installed as a Cygwin package, and the line in setup.py modified to: `libraries=['pocketsphinx', 'sphinxbase', 'iconv']`?

Comment: If you got an error during installation, why do you think the package is installed?

Comment: Thank you again. I then executed it on linux and it worked for me!!