# Check for working CXX compiler: /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/clang++ -- broken

Tags: c++, cmake, cygwin, clang++, iconv

I'm trying to install CLion and get my compiler to work but no matter what I do it keeps giving me the error stated above. It is able to detect clang just fine but it can't detect clang++. What is the reason for this?

The full error is shown below:

```
Check for working CXX compiler: /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/clang++ -- broken
CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/.CLion2018.1/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.10.3/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/clang++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/CLionProjects/trivialtest/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_79d96/fast"
    /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_79d96.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_79d96.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/CLionProjects/trivialtest/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_79d96.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/clang++     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_79d96.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /cygdrive/c/CLionProjects/trivialtest/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    Linking CXX executable cmTC_79d96.exe
    /cygdrive/c/.CLion2018.1/system/cygwin_cmake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_79d96.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/clang++    -Wl,--enable-auto-import  CMakeFiles/cmTC_79d96.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o  -o cmTC_79d96.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_79d96.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 
    /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/ld: cannot find -liconv
    clang-5.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_79d96.dir/build.make:98: cmTC_79d96.exe] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/CLionProjects/trivialtest/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    make: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_79d96/fast] Error 2




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/CLionProjects/trivialtest/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/c/CLionProjects/trivialtest/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

This is the CMakeError.log:

```
 Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
 Compiler: /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/clang++ 
 Build flags: 
 Id flags:  

 The output was:
 1
 /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/ld: cannot find -liconv
 clang-5.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

 Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the following output:
 Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/CLionProjects/trivialtest/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

 Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_79d96/fast"
 /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_79d96.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_79d96.dir/build
 make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/CLionProjects/trivialtest/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
 Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_79d96.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
 /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/clang++     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_79d96.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /cygdrive/c/CLionProjects/trivialtest/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
 Linking CXX executable cmTC_79d96.exe
 /cygdrive/c/.CLion2018.1/system/cygwin_cmake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_79d96.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
 /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/clang++    -Wl,--enable-auto-import  CMakeFiles/cmTC_79d96.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o  -o cmTC_79d96.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_79d96.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 
 /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/ld: cannot find -liconv
 clang-5.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_79d96.dir/build.make:98: cmTC_79d96.exe] Error 1
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/CLionProjects/trivialtest/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
 make: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_79d96/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: I know this is a stretch.  But, did you consider posting the log they say to look at for details?

Comment: Use `edit`, and add it to question as quoted source code.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Done!! I didn't put the output log because it was too long

Comment: Add 5 spaces after the `>`.  Quoted code, not just quoted.  I am on phone or would edit myself.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont like that?

Answer (score 1):

If the linker does not find `-liconv` it is looking for a library named `libiconv`. You could try installing it in your cygwin installation.

My guess would be that installing [this package](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fcygwin32-libiconv%2Fcygwin32-libiconv-1.14-2&grep=libiconv) will help.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to install `cygwin32-libiconv` in the answer from 2018 does not appear to be helpful, as it pertains to using 64-bit Cygwin cross-compiling to 32-bit.

Instead, to fix the OP's problem, or a problem such as:

```
  clang++ helloworld.cpp
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -liconv
```

install `libiconv-devel`.

In more detail, the Cygwin Package Search for a x86_64 `libiconv` gives several dozen lines, but the likely hits boil down to three, all having identical descriptions:

```
  libiconv:       Unicode iconv() implementation
  libiconv2:      Unicode iconv() implementation
  libiconv-devel: Unicode iconv() implementation
```

When you look at each package's full listing, you see that the first gives you `iconv.exe`, the second `cygiconv-2.dll`, and finally the third gives you `/usr/lib/libiconv.a`.

Related question: [Error when compiling sphinxbase in cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862180/error-when-compiling-sphinxbase-in-cygwin).